# Java/Scala SAML client example needed

Tags: java, scala, oauth, office365, saml

I'm writing some Scala code that will run on a server.  It needs to periodically connect to Office 365 to pull some data using OData.  I don't have access to AD to register an app.  I'm using a username and password for authentication.

Are there any suitable Java or Scala libraries I can use for the authentication step?  At the very least, I'd love to see some sample code in any language that shows the authentication step.  (Please don't provide samples that use a .Net library for the authentication step.  I need to be able to reproduce the logic in a JVM on Linux.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent example at https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml, which provides a class to prepare the request and  a class to process the response. There are some things  to fill in, but the wikipedia entry on SAML should be enough.